# Getting error Read-only file system: 'CO.dat' in python lambda prgrm

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Getting error [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'CO.dat' in python lambda prgrm  while running this portion of code

```py
file_n = 'CO.dat'
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

with open(file_n, 'wb') as f:       
    s3_client.download_fileobj('dev-itr-uls-weekly-files', key, f)
```

I tried

```
with open('/tmp/'+file_n, 'wb') as f:
```

which gives error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tmp/CO.dat'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was some file name issue .
The code

```
with open('/tmp/'+file_n, 'wb') as f:
```

solves

> [Errno 30] Read-only file system